# ngOnChanges does not work when value is passed from parent to child

Tags: angular

Why does ngOnChanges not get triggered even after the value of `child_message` is changing? I see that ngDocheck() gets triggered when value is passed from parent to child. However it gets triggered multiple times and not only when value is passed but also when component is initialized.I want something that gets triggered when value is changed after initialization.

**ParentComponent.ts**:

```js
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild,AfterViewInit, OnChanges, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from '../child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit,OnChanges{
  parent_message = "parent talking";
  @Input() clicked:boolean =false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(){
    //subscribing to message !!
    //this.data.currentMesssage.subscribe(message => this.message =message)
  }
  ngOnChanges(){
    console.log("change occured")
  }
  onClick(){
    this.clicked = true;
  }
}
```

**ParentComponent.html**:

```html
   <h1>Parent </h1>
Message:{{message}}
<button (click)='onClick()'>Send Message</button> 
<div *ngIf="clicked; else notclicked">
    <app-child  [childMessage]="parent_message"> </app-child>
</div>
<ng-template #notclicked>
    <app-child> </app-child>
</ng-template>
```

**ChildComponent.ts**:

```js
    import { Component, OnInit ,Input, Output,EventEmitter,OnChanges,DoCheck} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css'],
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges, DoCheck{
  @Input() childMessage: string ="child here ";
  //@Output()messageEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
  constructor() { }
  ngOnChanges(){
    console.log("change occured");
  }
  ngDoCheck(){
    console.log("ngDoCheck");
  }
}
```

**ChildComponent.html**:

```html
   <h1>Child</h1>
Say:{{childMessage}}
```

Comment: if I am not wrong, ngOnchanges is fired if the value is changed and not everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `ngDoCheck()` life cycle hook instead.

> This hook is called during every change detection run.

```js
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
      message = "parent talking";  

      ngOnInit(){ }

      ngDoCheck(){
        console.log("change occured")
      }

      receiveMessage($event){
        this.message = $event;  
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementation has 2 mistakes 
 - Value change is not happening
 - Value is not correctly passed to child component
You can see sample implementation just refer
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

> Angular calls its ngOnChanges() method whenever it detects changes to input properties of the component (or directive).

If you bind any property with the template and the value of the property has changed it's value then the `ngOnChanges()` will trigger.

We need to remember when bind property is an Object then `ngOnChanges()` will only fire if you change entire object.

Just change this line in your Parent Template, it will work fine.

```
<app-child (messageEvent)="receiveMessage($event)"  [child_message]="message"> </app-child>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a message from child to parent you need to implement like this

```
  @Output()  // in child class
  nextStep = new EventEmitter();
  // you can call with data in some function like on click oo input changed
  this.nextStep.emit({key: 'value'});
```

In your parent component you can get value from the `$event` object

```
<app-child  (nextStep)="someParentFUnction($event, acc)"></app-child>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code.

In your parent template, you pass `parent_message` property bu that doesn't exist in the `ParentComponent`

```
<app-child (messageEvent)="receiveMessage($event)" [child_message]="parent_message"> </app-child>
//                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                                                  this needs to be "message" property of ParentComponent
```

And again in the same line:

```
<app-child (messageEvent)="receiveMessage($event)" [child_message]="parent_message"> </app-child>
//                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                                   this needs to be "childMessage" property of ChildComponent
```

And as told in the [official docs](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges), `ngOnChanges` is fired after a data-bound properties such as `@Input` are changed. Therefore it does not fire.